# Infinite item source for creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any mod which adds infinite item source? What I mean is - I want to have a block like chest, barrel from *Factorization*, storage unit from *Minefactory Reloaded* or items monitor from *Applied Energistics* but with ability to store **infinite** amount of items (for example by right clicking with this item in hand on storage block). I want to be able (in creative mode) to pump items from that storage block without any amount limitations by *BuildCraft* pipes, *Thermal Expansion* conduits or *Computer Craft* turtles (especially *Computer Craft* turtles). Is it possible some how?

Comment: By limitations by the various pipes do you mean speed limitations

Comment: @Flaunting, I meant amount limitation

Comment: The trouble with this is that the more items you have, the more ram it'll take up, so it will eventually end up causing severe lag issues

Comment: @Ben, I understand that and that's the risk i'm willing to take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is the Deep Storage Unit - Minefactory Reloaded - This can store 2 billion of a single item. This is the biggest form of storage you can get. To fill it quickly the best way is.

> This will only work in SP if you don't have access to the server.
>
> Clear your inventory (optional, but makes it easier)
>
> Get one of the item you want a lot of
>
> Edit your player file with an NBT editor
>
> Change the amount of the item to like 2000000000
>
> Log back in, don't die or there will be a ton of lag.

then place the rather large stack into the DSU.

If you wanted to pump this out quickly your best option is applied energistics. but any pipe system will work. It completely depends on how quickly.

The only infinite source is using the Jabba creative upgrade but this has been buggy in my experience when connected to pipe networks and has crashed my server several times when too many items get taken out.